# Knife Tool Project - Cutting Away Volume

Tags: modeling, mesh, knife-tool

I am trying to create a model for 3D printing. I am trying to have this cylinder and hexagon shape "cut away" from the main mesh. How could I do this? It is to be the negative space of a bolt and a nut (nut fed into the hold on the inside)

**[Blend File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/253/)**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: use the [Boolean modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans)

Comment: @Chebhou drat, you beat me to it. Do you want to put that in an answer??

Comment: Chebhouuuuuu if you don't answer can I? *whimpers* it soo tempting.

Comment: @ARadish nope go ahead,  sorrrry

Comment: @Chebhou Please avoid answering the question in the comments. Comments are for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Boolean* modifier to do this. Create an object that is the exact shape of the hole you want, then select the object you want the hole in, and add the modifier. You can now select the name of the object you want to use to create the hole. Now change the boolean  method to *Difference*, press the *Apply* button, and delete the mesh you used to make the hole.

[image: Boolean Modifier]